# creating a smooth image animation over time with CSS

Tags: css, animation

Discord has a nicely animated page

https://discordapp.com/

The coins are moving up and down really smoothly. How can I copy this logic for my own images?

I started with this code

```css
img {
  animation-name: move;
  animation-duration: 2.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://gonintendo.com/system/file_uploads/uploads/000/013/369/original/bg-header-earn-coins.png">
```

When testing the code the image is not moving smoothly. I thought using `animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;` would do it for me.

Is something missing there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to animations, duration and distance moved are highly important.  The type of animation is also important.  Using margins instead of CSS `transform`s makes it less likely that the GPU will be used, which is generally better at animating than not using GPU.

Basically, your code is not a faithful recreation of the timing and animation styles as are used on discord.  This is closer:

```css
img {
  animation-name: move;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0,-4px,0)
  }

  to {
    transform: translate3d(0,4px,0)
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://gonintendo.com/system/file_uploads/uploads/000/013/369/original/bg-header-earn-coins.png">
```